# Automount LDAP home directories on custom directory

Tags: automount

Im trying to automount home directories which exported from an IPA server to a client.The setup is the following one :

```
auto.master:
/home/ldap    /etc/ldap.file

ldap.file :
* -rw,sync server:/home/ldap/&
```

This setup apparently works , but if I modified it to :

```
 auto.master:
/home/guests    /etc/ldap.file

ldap.file :
* -rw,sync server:/home/ldap/&
```

it doesn't :

```
  su - ldapuser20
  su: warning: cannot change directory to /home/ldap/ldapuser20: No such 
  file or directory
```

In order for automount to work ,is it necessary the client side to have set 
 the same directory as NFS export (/home/ldap on client should be the same as /home/ldap NFS export) ?
 I made numerous attempts with other custom directories from client side and all of them failed.
 Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary that the nfs export is mounted in same path on client machine; you can mount it where you please.

However, what you have specified as home directories for the users, either in LDAP or where ever that attribute is stored, must map with the settings in your automount configuration for it to work. IF you change from `/home/ldap` to `/home/guests` then those changes needs to be reflected also in the user account.  If you use the IPA, check the ldap `homeDirectory` attribute of your user.

Finally, if you change something in the user account then old data may still be cached by `sssd` (if you use that). If that's the case you can try swiping `sssd` cache and reloading the daemon.

Comment: thanks Petter, I've changed the home directory attribute from IPA server and actually worked! thanks a lot!